# Adding a property to a Model in the ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

With the Model

```
public class Person {
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname  { get; set; }
    public string DOB      { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ViewModel which I'll be passing through to the View

```
public class PersonViewModel {
    public IQueryable<Person> PersonVM { get; set; }
    public string sometext{ get; set; }
}
```

If, for example, I wanted to calculate the age in the controller code and store it against each `Person` row in the `IQueryable` so it could be seen in the View, what's the best way of adding an Age property to each row?

I'm guessing that I don't have to include a fake property in the `Person` model like so

```
    public string Age      { get; set; }
```

Comment: Did you used any mapping library which map viewmodel to model like automapper ?

Comment: Is this Age saved in database or only used to calculate at run time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NotMapped attribute which will exclude the property from database mapping.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mixing both of these answers together solves a few other problems, so that's what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Age` property `set private` and write your logic in `get` to calculate it at run time.

```
public class Person {
  public string Forename { get; set; }
  public string Surname  { get; set; }
  public string DOB      { get; set; }
  public string Age {
                      get{
                            //.... you logic
                      }
                      private set{}

}
```

Comment: Mixing both of these answers together solves a few other problems, so that's what I've done. Can only give tick answer to one person though, sorry.